# Submit form with <selector> on another website

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

They have a selector on `example.com`. And my Nodejs server is running on `myserver.com`

```
<form method="POST" name="formname">
<select name="selector" onchange="document.forms['formname'].submit();">
```

When you select an option it updates the content of the page.

How can I simulate selecting the `First option` on `example.com` from `myserver.com` to receive the page content (only nodejs).

(I think the best solution would be with the Request module)

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to find out what request this actually causes ... and then make the same request …?

Comment: I think you would need to use something like node phantom js then you should be able to achieve this.